# How to add a digital signature to xml payload in mule

Tags: mule

I am trying to add a digital signature.
My input is an xml payload.
I am using xml_signer as the default signer and the jce-signer-config algorithm as "HmacMD5"

My flow is like below

```
    <flow name="Flow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sign" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="Original payload:  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <signature:sign   config-ref="Signature" doc:name="Signature"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Payload with signature #[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />

</flow>
```

My input payload is like below:

```
 <PurchaseOrder>
   <Item number="130046593231">
    <Description>Video Game</Description>
    <Price>10.29</Price>
    </Item>
    <Buyer id="8492340">
   <Name>My Name</Name>
   <Address>
   <Street>One Network Drive</Street>
   <Town>Burlington</Town>
   <State>MA</State>
   <Country>United States</Country>
   <PostalCode>01803</PostalCode>
   </Address>
   </Buyer>
  </PurchaseOrder>
```

My expected payload :

```
<PurchaseOrder>
<Item number="130046593231">
<Description>Video Game</Description>
<Price>10.29</Price>
 </Item>
 <Buyer id="8492340">
 <Name>My Name</Name>
 <Address>
 <Street>One Network Drive</Street>
 <Town>Burlington</Town>
 <State>MA</State>
 <Country>United States</Country>
 <PostalCode>01803</PostalCode>
</Address>
</Buyer>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
   <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="">
      <Transforms>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>   
      </Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>  

      <DigestValue>tkrLEansVMTKqAOuW6b8Dx+OUNWk9bVpW6RFvfuEmM8=     </DigestValue>
        </Reference>
      </SignedInfo> 

    <SignatureValue>

   PeeHVw+XvZkkhhPlEopRp1PBDfTcR9U2IBimTTo1gOMF5cWq1tFqZ0B4ScNBiZVtd0yS4j06xl3
    WB2Q87oobwA==
     </SignatureValue>
   <KeyInfo>
 <KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>i8OP+VX/EORWwHiHiqLmMgpXz4IubPv2y+gHdiSCUzKoFfUYD6wFGBwi6vVmRSrmNbNZvZ9DFvST
     PZJEyUhn5w==</Modulus>
         <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
            </KeyValue></KeyInfo>
            </Signature></PurchaseOrder>
```

Actual output:

```
  <PurchaseOrder>
    <Item number="130046593231">
    <Description>Video Game</Description>
 <Price>10.29</Price>
</Item>
 <Buyer id="8492340">
 <Name>My Name</Name>
 <Address>
  <Street>One Network Drive</Street>
 <Town>Burlington</Town>
  <State>MA</State>
  <Country>United States</Country>
  <PostalCode>01803</PostalCode>
  </Address>
  </Buyer>
 </PurchaseOrder>
```

I am following this link : https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-digital-signature-processor

I followed these steps:

(1) Add a global Signature message processor to your application, applying a unique Name for the element and keeping the default value, JCE_SIGNER, in the Default Signer field.

(2) Click the JceSigner tab, then configure the message processor’s attributes according to the table below.

(3) Add a Signature message processor to your flow.

(4) Configure the message processor’s fields according to the table.

Why am I not getting the expected output? How can I add a digital signature ?